# Dynamic query in EF using Expression

Tags: entity-framework-core, dynamicquery

I am trying to understand what is the best way to create a dynamic query.

I have a requirement where I will be writing an API to retrieve data from DB. the API has lot of filter paramters. eg. I need to retrieve movies that can  be filtered on following  properties.

```
MovieName, Genere, Rating, Language, Category
```

I can give these parameters in any combination.. so in my Data layer I started framing my dynamic query like this.

```
IQueryable<Movie> qryContext = null;
```

if(!string.isnullorEmpty(request.MovieName))
qryContext  = context.Movies.Where(x => x.MovieName == request.MovieName)

if(!string.isnullorEmpty(request.Genere))
qryContext  = context.Movies.Where(x => x.Genere == request.Genere)

if(!string.isnullorEmpty(request.Language))
qryContext  = context.Movies.Where(x => x.Language == request.Language)

if(!string.isnullorEmpty(request.Category))
qryContext  = context.Movies.Where(x => x.Category == request.Category)

if(qryContext!= null)
return qryContext.ToList();
else
return null;

Based on the given parameters, the sql query is  framed..

---

But When I search in google reg dynamic queries in EF, most of the links  refer to  using Expression. Do I need to make use of Expression or can I proeeed with the above method.

Also let me know what advantage I  get on  using expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you see inside the Where(...) is expression.
In your example this would be x => x.Language == request.Language

```
if(!string.isnullorEmpty(request.Language)) qryContext = context.Movies.Where(x => x.Language == request.Language)
```

Also, I would recommend you to take a look into the Dynamic expression library from EF Plus team. Here https://dynamic-linq.net/basic-simple-query

This allows you to pass expression as a string. And you can construct your filters in the Frontend, and pass them as a string, which helps you to write a much cleaner implementation of filters.